# How to calculate Mahalanobis distance in SPSS for an exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: spss, factor-analysis, distance

I have a question regarding data screening for an exploratory factor analysis (EFA).

I am conducting an EFA to identify the factor structure of 20 questions that I created on the topic of spirituality. I want to identify outliers in my sample using mahalanobis distances, and I am doing this on SPSS using a linear regression (`Analyze -> Regression -> Linear`).

- I entered the 20 questions in SPSS as the "Independents", but what would variable should be entered under the "Dependent" category?
- Or, if I can't use SPSS to find the mahalanobis distances, is there another (easy!!) way to find the m distances?

Comment: SPSS can compute Mahalanobis distances as a by-product in Linear regression and Discriminant analysis procedures. More convenient for you could be to use a special function to compute them. Take it from my web-page (Matrix - End Matrix functions). There are 2 functions for Mah. d. You'll need the second one, I guess.

Comment: P.S. @Madeline, in responce to your 1st question: in SPSS linear regression, specify any variable as as dependent (for example, respondent's ID number); check to save Mah.d. under Save button. That would be the most easy way for you. It will save that same squared distances as my function !smahalc computes.

Comment: Thank you ttnphns for you help! Also, I had to reverse code a few of the questions - does it matter if I enter the reverse coded or the "regular" responses when calculating mah. distances?

Comment: I can't get exactly what you mean under "reverse code" but, anyway, you could do both ways to see if the result will change.

Comment: Psychological researchers sometimes generate "negatively worded" questions and place them in questionnaires that they have developed to sustain participants' attention (ex. I do NOT think that my life has a purpose). When entering data for negatively worded questions, it is easier to enter the actual paraticipant response (such as 6 = "strongly disagree") and then "reverse code" the answer later (change the response to its opposite, i.e. 1 = strongly agree) in order to reflect the positive version of the question (i.e. I DO think that my life has a purpose).

Comment: @ttnphns, Please post that as an answer. I would have thought you could simply use the `PROXIMITIES` command, but I see it is not an option. Good to know, I've never seen it used as a diagnostic tool for linear regression in my work so I would have never looked there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a procedure:

1. Create a dummy variable and move this variable to dependent variable box.
2. Run linear regression process as usual.
3. Save Mahalanobis score. (A new variable will be created in your data file.)

Extraordinarily large scores will be outliers.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Muhammad-Rahid. I took the liberty of editing your answer to make it more readable & in-line w/ the sites policies, I hope you don't mind. Since you're new here, you may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).